# creating a txt file to call f2() without modiying the code

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow

creating a txt file to call f2() without modiying the code how to input the file  and not modify this code the file will have the adress of f2() then the program will print "hello
World"

note: my f2() address is 00 40 10 14 and in reverse for the buffer over flow it will be read like 14 10 40 00

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;
int i;
unsigned int* p;

void f1() {
    int a=10;
    char str[4];

    cout << "Please enter a string:";
    while (!cin.eof()) {
        cin.get(str[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("address of str is:%x\n",str);
    printf("address of a is:%x\n",&a);
    cout << "The string you entered is:";
    cout << str << endl;
}

void f2()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
}

main()
{ 
    printf("The address of function f2:%08x\n",f2);
    f1();
}
```

Comment: Text files don't *call* anything. It's just text. Can you rephrase?

Comment: am supposed to creat a txt file that will buffer overflow the address of F1() and the address header will re direct me to f2() and print Hello world from F2() whats required is .txt file that fill cause the bufferoverflow and how can i insert the file without modifing the source code

Answer (score 0):

You may look at example for buffer overrun
like http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roberthorvick/archive/2004/01/16/59460.aspx